# Using chroot to restore Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, chroot, live-usb, kubuntu

I have accidentaly purged some system files and now Kubuntu 14.04 won't boot past the start up logo.

I read online that I can perform changes on my system through my LiveUSB and the BASH `chroot` command.

How can I explicitly 'reinstall' the essential files from my LiveUSB to my system?

Im am fairly new to Linux and not entirely sure about mounting disks, mountpoints, etc., which I understand is necessry to use `chroot`.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered a number of times online, these two look like a pretty good place to start:

[What's the proper way to prepare chroot to recover a broken Linux installation?](https://superuser.com/questions/111152/whats-the-proper-way-to-prepare-chroot-to-recover-a-broken-linux-installation)
[How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels)

If you have specific problems while going through a tutorial you can create a question for that (provided it hasn't already been answered). Good Luck!

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have found the second link myself and tried it out previously, but got an error after step 3, line 2, telling me that the mount point didn't exist(?!). As I said, not too sure about mounting...

Comment: A mount point is just an existing file path. So if you get an error: `mount: mount point /foo/bar does not exist` you can fix it with: `mkdir -p /foo/bar` (You may need to be root in oder to make the directory depending on where you are trying to make it.)